# Triangle with the lowest laplacian eigenvalue under the Dirichlet boundary condition

Tags: spectral-theory, laplacian, eigenfunctions

Let us fix the area of the triangle. Which triangle has the lowest Laplacian eigenvalue? The equilateral one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Steiner symmetrization decreases the first Dirichlet eigenvalue (also known as the fundamental frequency), unless the domain is already symmetric. And a triangle that is not equilateral can be Steiner-symmetrized in a nontrivial way.

More generally, Pólya and Szegő conjectured that among all $n$-gons of fixed area the regular $n$-gon has the lowest fundamental frequency. This has been proved (by symmetrization) for $n=3,4$. Remains open for $n\ge 5$.

I don't have a reference to original source, but the statement can be found in

- Antoine Henrot. [*Minimization problems for eigenvalues of the Laplacian*](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00115548/document). Journal of Evolution Equations, Springer Verlag, 2003, 3, pp.443-461.
- Bartłomiej Siudeja. [*Isoperimetric inequalities for eigenvalues of triangles*](http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.3631),  Indiana Univ. Math. J. 59 (2010), no. 3, 1097–1120

Also, the classical source of such problems is

- George Pólya, Gábor Szegő. [*Isoperimetric Inequalities in Mathematical Physics*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Isoperimetric_Inequalities_in_Mathematic.html?id=HWc8gFW2XXgC). Princeton University Press, 1951